# for loop, failed to load given URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to js, and I'm playing about with a for loop that places images into a #div using .append()

totalSlides is a dynamic int and can change, I want to display the same amount of images as the number of totalSlides.

I'm pretty sure the for loop logic is correct, but for some reason the images are not displaying. When i inspect in firebug i get the error "failed to load given url". I know that that url is correct, i have even tried the full url path C:/complete/folder/path etc..

I'm sure it's an easy fix that i should get but for now i just can't see why it won't load my images.

```
for(i=0;i<totalSlides;i++){ // Loads all number images into html
    $('#numbers').append("<img src='images/numbers/number"+i+".png'/>");
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Jase

Comment: if you're not using http URLs, there may be issues.  Browsers have begun denying access to filesystem URLs due to some security issues.  Make sure the image is accessible via `http://localhost/something` and try that.

Comment: If Firebug says that the URL failed to load, I don't think the URL is correct, esp. if it starts with `C:/`. Or can you open such URL directly in your browser?

Comment: @Gus Bingo, somethings not right here, as i can't seem to access images through the http://localhost/ Gives me somewhere to look and hunt down. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any kind of MVC frameworks?  The root url paths will be set differently.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be if the JavaScript is located in other folder (e.g. /js/myfile.js) then the relative path will fail since it will look for the images folder *inside the JS folder*.

Try giving path starting from the root:

```
$('#numbers').append("<img src='/images/numbers/number"+i+".png'/>");
```

(Note the added "/" in the beggining of the image source)

Comment: Hi Shadow Wizard, I have tried your suggestion, along with '../' prefix also. Still no joy.

Comment: Can you see the actual image URL being requested? E.g. by using Firebug?